# Using DLLImport to call c++ from C#, Object reference not found error

Tags: c#, c++, dllimport

I am trying to call a c++ dll from C# using DLLImport, and am hitting a 'Object reference not found' error.

I have done this before, so i am definitely missing something, but what?

in C#, I have:

```
[DllImport("Test.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void Tester();
```

and the function:

```
 public void ConnectionGo()
        {
             Tester();
        }
```

in the dll, i have:

```
extern "C"
{
    _declspec(dllexport) void Tester()
    {
        std::cout << "Okay" << std::endl;
    }

};
```

The dll is in the same directory as the C# exe (it is a WPF application).
They are both built as 'Release'.

And yet i get this error:

```
'Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: I don't know because the above codes can not cause this exception. You should know which line throw it don't you?

Comment: As soon as I run the `Tester();` function, the application crashes with the error.

Comment: Try run with debugger.

Comment: Aha! I had not initialised a class properly. Of course, it was user error. Thank you for your time.